# how user be able to Add, edit and see their own topics and topic's description?

Tags: asp.net

how user be able to Add and see all topics and can EDIT only his own topic, topic's description? am doing this in asp.net using c# created topic table in mysql server havin topic id ,topic and topic description column.am much beginer in this so detailed help plz
i want that userId save in topic tble so that user can edit his own topic.want to use userid from register table which is asign to user when user registered.did this which is not good.this code for adding topics

```
String sql = "insert into T_TOPIC(TOPIC,DESCRIPTION,USER_ID) values(@TOPIC,@DESCRIPTION,@USER_ID)";

        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sql, con);


        com.Parameters.Add("@TOPIC", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.TXT_BOX_TOPIC.Text;
        com.Parameters.Add("@USER_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = this.TXT_BOX_USER_ID.Text;
        com.Parameters.Add("@DESCRIPTION", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.TXT_BOX_DESC.Text;
```

Comment: Please elaborate your question with some code.

Answer (score 0):

you must add `UserId` to `topic table` where you'll write `Id` of topic owner `user`

THen, when you want to give to user only his topicks you'll ned write a simple `sql` `query` like:

```
select * from topic table where UserId = 5(for example)
```

Comment: hmmm.. user id is in registration tbl. now how can i add user id in topic tbl? previously am using this querry "SELECT * FROM T_TOPIC WHERE TOPIC_ID = @TOPIC_ID";